# Error while setting up grafana with graphite and nginx

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, graphite, cors

While trying to setup grafana with graphite using nginx server. I am getting this error:
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
I tried changing configuration file but still not working my grafana configuration file:

```
#Grafana Server Configuration
server {
  listen 9400;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/grafana.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/grafana.error.log;

  location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "ip address of the server";
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";
    root /usr/share/grafana;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add full URL to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, like:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com";
```

Comment: I did that but still not working

Comment: You used the actual domain name that is including the resource in its code?

Comment: I gave like this "http://ipaddesss:8080"

Comment: And you are accessing the page with `http://ip_address:8080/` in your browser?

Comment: Yes  I am able to access that link

Comment: I have given only http://ipaddress not 8080

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298751/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-for-grafana` This is the same thing which I am doing and facing the same issue.